# Does every Hamel basis for an infinite dimensional topological vector space have a maximal countable spanning subset?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

‎‎‎‎Let ‎$ X $ ‎be an  infinite dimensional topological vector space and 
‎$\{ e‎_{i}: i ‎\in I ‎\}$‎ be a Hamel basis for $X$. 
Does there exist a maximal countable subset  ‎$J‎\subset ‎I$ ‎such ‎that for all ‎$a‎\in ‎X$ ‎there ‎are‎ ‎$j‎_{1}, \ldots, j‎_{k}‎\in J‎$ such that $a=‎\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}e_{j_i}‎$‎?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't in general.

If $J$ were such a set then $J$ would span the whole vector space. So we would have $J=I$. So your question can be reduced to the question if there exists vector spaces with an uncountable basis. Each infinite dimensional Banach space is such a space. For example take $C_0([0,1])$ with supremum norm.

Comment: Thanks, yes ‎$ X $ ‎is  a topological vector space with an uncountable basis. Then the above claim is correct?

Comment: @user266582 As I explained, in case $X$ has an uncountable basis there is no such $J$ because $J$ would be a countable basis and the cardinality  of each basis is the same. Furthermore, the proper subset of a basis of a vector space is never a basis of the vector space but the basis of a proper subspace.